# WPF XAML clipping ellipse on canvas when using TranslateTransform

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I run this code in WPF it gives me 1/4 of a circle. When removing the ClipToBounds tag, i get my whole circle. 
1. Why is it clipping before rendering?
2. How to i fix that, while keeping clipping?

```
<Canvas ClipToBounds="True">
    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="-10"
             Canvas.Top="-10"
             Width="20"
             Height="20"
             Fill="LightSeaGreen"/>
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="4.8"
                            ScaleY="4.8"
                            CenterX="0"
                            CenterY="0"/>
            <TranslateTransform X="48"
                                Y="48"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
</Canvas>
```

[image: Picture of rendered code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *Why* is it clipping before rendering?

   - It's not.
     As you can see from here:
     [image: The Ellipse]
     Your `Ellipse` is rendered perfectly. The `ClipToBounds="True"` is what ruins is as you can see from your `Canvas`: 
     [image: The Canvas]
2. *How* to i fix that, while keeping clipping?

   - This is quite a broad question. Your problem comes from the fact you are putting your `Ellipse` outside the `Canvas` (`Canvas.Left="-10" Canvas.Top="-10"`) and then you clip it. Explain what is your goal and I can try to help you out.

Comment: I am following through the examples in a textbook (Computer Graphics). Thinking about it, in my simple mind, it seems silly to clip before performing transforms, as the renderer doesnt know the final locations of objects until transformed.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is by design.  The authors of the textbook (*Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice - Third Edition*) have confusingly introduced `ClipToBounds` in a way that makes it seem like it is a part of the examples that follow in the book.  In fact, they are *not* using `ClipToBounds="True"`.  You can verify that by downloading their lab package from http://sklardevelopment.com/graftext/ChapWPF2D/ .

To illustrate, here is the actual source code for one of their examples:

```
<Canvas
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
  Name="ClockCanvas" >

    <Ellipse
       Width="20.0" Height="20.0"
       Canvas.Left="-10.0" Canvas.Top="-10.0"
       Fill="lightgray"/>

</Canvas>
```

Note that there is no `ClipToBounds="True"` on the canvas.